# MouseButtons.XButton1/2 not detected

Tags: c#, mono, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to use my extra mouse buttons in a C# application. The three standard mouse buttons are working fine with this code:

```
class Window:Form {
  public Window() {
    this.Width = 400;
    this.Height = 280;
    this.MouseDown += this.OnMouseDown;
  }

  public void OnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    this.Text = e.Button.ToString();
  }
}
```

But for some reason I don't get anything from the two extra mouse buttons, which should show "XButton1" or "XButton2". The extra buttons are working fine for navigating in firefox. Is there something I overlooked? Any help appreciated :)

eta: I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Microsoft says that they support this, you can check the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx. Probably the problem is in Mono.

Comment: You're right. I just tried to run the code on a friend's computer's Visual Studio, and it detected the extra buttons just fine. I'll try to contact the Mono developers about it. Many thanks! :)